# How do I select two separate inputs in each tr using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html table:

```
<table id='table1'>
     <tr>
         <td>String</td>
         <td><input type='text' id='first-input-01'></input></td>
         <td><input type='text' id='second-input-01'></input></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>String</td>
         <td><input type='text' id='first-input-02'></input></td>
         <td><input type='text' id='second-input-02'></input></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Total:</td>
         <td> </td>
         <td>(total goes here)</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

and using jQuery, I want to find the value of #first-input-xx and multiply it by #second-input-xx for each table row, adding up each row to an overall total. However, I'm finding it difficult to select each input for each table row. I'm trying:

```
var total = 0;

$("#table1 tr").each(function() {
    var amount1 = $(this).children("td:nth-last-child(2) input").val();
    var amount2 = $(this).children("td:last input").val();
    total = total + (parseFloat(amount1) * parseFloat(amount2));
});
```

Appreciative of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: use **[eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)**

```
var total = 0;

$("#table1 tr").each(function () {
    var input = $(this).find('input');
    if (input.length == 2) {
        total += input.eq(0).val() * input.eq(1).val();
    }
    console.log(total)
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vmxrca1d/15/)**

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. Although, what does the .length test achieve? I'm given a total of "NaN" when I don't test for input.length == 2. I would've guessed that the last row of the table with no input elements on it would cause NaN but I get NaN when I change it to input.length > 0.

Comment: you get 2 input box only  that is why i  checked  input.length == 2,And also i don't want calculate total without any text box  in tr ,if we without checking it will return NAN

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use .children() as you are trying to find the input element, instead use .find()

```
var total = 0;

$("#table1 tr").each(function () {
    var amount1 = $(this).find("td:eq(-2) input").val();
    var amount2 = $(this).find("td:last input").val();
    total += (parseFloat(amount1) * parseFloat(amount2)) || 0;
});
alert(total)
```

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var total = 0;

  $("#table1 tr").each(function() {
    var amount1 = $(this).find("td:eq(-2) input").val();
    var amount2 = $(this).find("td:last input").val();
    total += (parseFloat(amount1) * parseFloat(amount2)) || 0;
  });
  alert(total)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='table1'>
  <tr>
    <td>String</td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='first-input-01'></input>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='second-input-01'></input>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>String</td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='first-input-02'></input>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' id='second-input-02'></input>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#table1 tr").each(function() {
    var amount1 = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").val();
    var amount2 = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").val();
    total = total + (parseFloat(amount1) * parseFloat(amount2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have added few codes. please check it out.

```
$("#calculate_btn").click(function(){
var total=0;
var row_mux=1;
$("#table1 tr").each(function(key,val){

  $(val).find("input").each(function(k,v){

   row_mux*=parseFloat($(v).val());

  });
  total=row_mux++;
});
alert(total);
$("#table1 tr:last").find("td:last").html(total);
});
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjwVma)